# How to scanf full sentence in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

How to `scanf()` full sentence  in C without using `fgets()` or `gets()`

I want to scan a command line from the user and based on the first word recognize the command. 
For example:
    mkdir

so I need to recognize that the user wants to create a new dir with the name "dir_name".

My code:

```
int main(){
  char *ch=malloc(sizeof("50");
  while (strcmp(ch,"exit")!=0){
     scanf("%[^\n]",ch);
  }
```

when i ran this code after i input the first sentence and press enter it went to infinity loop i don't know why?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `fgets`?  Using it to read a full line then `sscanf` to later parse the line sounds much easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
char *ch=malloc(sizeof("50");
```

To begin with, you're missing one close parentheses. But assuming that this was a typo in posting the question and not in your actual code, there is a deeper issue.

`"50"` inside double quotes is a string literal. When `sizeof()` is applied to the string literal, you're going to get the number of characters in the string, including terminating `NUL`. So you are only allocating space for three characters in `ch`.

When you try to `scanf()` the input, you're writing past the end of your three-character buffer `ch`. Leave out `sizeof()` and simply say:

```
char* ch = malloc (50);
```

Also, the scan set `%[^\n]` does **not** skip leading whitespace. Your first `scanf()` will stop at the newline, which will remain in the buffer. Subsequent `scanf()` calls in your `while` loop will encounter that newline character and dutifully stop, as it's excluded from your scan set. So the loop condition

```
while (strcmp (ch, "exit"))
```

will never become true, and you'll get an infinite loop. Consume the newline after the `scanf()` to avoid this problem:

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", ch);
```

The `%*c` means "read a character and then discard it." So it will read the `\n` that is left in the buffer, and then not save it anywhere. Your next `scanf()` will therefore not encounter a `\n` at the beginning of the buffer, and your program will work as you intend.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now :) this was the problem : "scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", ch);" what is the meaning of the "%*c"? thanks again

Comment: Better to use `scanf ("%49[^\n]%*1[\n]", ch);` to limit input and only toss a `'\n'` with a long line.  Even that will not read anything if input is `"\n"` as it leaves the `'\n'` in `stdin`.  Suggest `fgetc()`.  Yet this answer well deals with OP's primary issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char  input_string[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&input_string);
    printf("Hello ,world.\n");
    printf("%s",input_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    int MAX_LEN = 100;
    char ch ; 
    char s [MAX_LEN]; 
    char sen [MAX_LEN]; 
    scanf("%c",&ch); 
    scanf("%s \n",&s); 
    scanf("%*[\n] %[^\n]", sen); 
    printf("%c \n",ch); 
    printf("%s \n",s); 
    printf("%s \n",sen); 
    return 0 ; 
    }
```

Comment: With this the new line character have been taken care of.  You can still use scanf("\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sen); This works just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%[^\n]s",s);` this will do you can also use `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);` where `s` is defined as `char s[MAX_LEN]` where  `MAX_LEN` is the maximum size of `s` . Here, `[]` is the scanset character. `^\n` stands for taking input until a newline isn't encountered. Then, with this `%*c,` it reads the newline character and here, the used `*` indicates that this newline character is discarded.